# SQL Server 2016 as a Database Server for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server

We have SQL Server 2008 R2 version as a database server for SharePoint 2010 Enterprise version.  Now we need to upgrade the SQL instance for the intranet which is build up using SharePoint 2010.

Can we have SQL Server 2016 as a database server for SharePoint 2010 Standard/Enterprise version?

Are SharePoint 2010 and SQL Server 2016 compatible?

Answer (score 9):

It is not supported, sharepoint 2010 is not supported on even Microsoft SQL Server 2014. 
If you read the software requirement MSFT give the equation which help to determine awl version support.

> In order to maintain SharePoint and SQL Server compatibility we use
>   the “SharePoint N-1 on SQL Server N+1”  equation to determine version
>   support. Using SharePoint Server 2010 as an example, the N release of
>   SQL Server is 2008/2008 R2 and N+1 is SQL Server 2012. For Microsoft
>   SharePoint Server 2013 the N release of SQL Server is 2012 and the N+1
>   is SQL Server 2014.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.14).aspx#section4